# What is the overnight wait room situation in bigger rail stations in Spain (Madrid and Valencia)?

Tags: spain, sleeping, train-stations, madrid, valencia

I'm currently building my itinerary for crossing Spain by land (need to get to Almeria) and the better train connections I found unfortunately arrive to their transit destinations (*Madrid Chamartín* or *Valencia Joaquín Sorolla*) at midnight with the connecting train leaving in the morning (8am-ish). I'm travelling on a tight budget so getting a hotel for those few hours is not really an option.

What waiting room facilities are available at of those rail stations? I'd really love to avoid sandwiching an anxious 8 hour wait in the middle of a train terminal between two +12h legs of my journey!

Comment: Can you share your itinerary? There might be a way to do it including a sleeper train or on a different route which might work better. From Valencia to Almería you'd need to take a detour via Alcázar de Sant Juan and there might be a better option...

Answer (score 1):

The station home pages and opening times are here http://www.adif.es/es_ES/infraestructuras/estaciones/17000/informacion_000295.shtml and here http://www.adif.es/es_ES/infraestructuras/estaciones/3216/informacion_000382.shtml

It looks like they are both closed overnight (*Horario de la estación*), so I would expect that you would get kicked out of the waiting room.

Almería is in Andalucia, so possibly another route rather than via Valencia will be more convenient.

HTH